# tensor product of smooth tensor field is also smooth tensor field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

let M be a smooth manifold ,and $A$ be a smooth covariant k-tensor and $B$ be a smooth covariant l-tensor.

Now prove $A\otimes B$ is also smooth tensor field.

My attempt: if $A\otimes B$ is a rough tensor field, then by evaluating at any smooth vector vector field on $M$ i.e.

$$A\otimes B(X_1,...,X_k,X_{k+1},...,X_{k+l})  = A(X_1,...,X_k)B(X_{k+1},...,X_{k+k})$$
is also smooth so $A\otimes B$ is smooth.

The question is how to prove $A\otimes B$ is a tensor field?

Where rough tensor field is a rough section ,for here we need to show $A\otimes B:M\to T^{k+l}(T^*M)$ is a rough section.Which always hold here since $(A\otimes B)_p \in T^{k+l}(T^*_pM)$ .The point here is how to show it's tensor field,that is why section is continuous.

Of coursse we can do it indirectly first prove the tensor field is smooth,since any smooth map between manifold is continuous the section is continuous,but how to prove it directly?

Comment: Please include the definition of rough tensor field in your post.

Comment: I have edited it, Do we need to show section is continuous, or just need to show at each point it lies on cotangent space is enough?

Comment: So what is a rough section?

Comment: @Arctic Char , thank you,I got it, there are three levels of section here.